# Display date picker in Magento checkout page

Tags: php, magento

I'm new to Magento and i want to add a date picker to Magento checkout page. I followed the below codings and could not be success. What's the wrong with them and if this is not the proper way what should i do to add the date picker to checkout page. Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
app/design/frontend/default/yourthemename/layout/page.xml

<action method=”addItem”><type>js_css</type>
<name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name>    
<params></params>
</action>
<action method=”addItem”><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name></action>
<action method=”addItem”><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name>    
</action>
<block type=”core/html_calendar” name=”head.calendar” as=”calendar”    
template=”page/js/calendar.phtml”></block>
```

I kept this code at IndexController.php at my test module.

```
<div class=”field”>
<label for=”delivery_date”><?php echo $this->__(‘Delivery Date’) ?></label>
<div class=”input-box”>
<input type=”text” id=”_dob” name=”delivery_date” class=”input-text required-entry” />    
<em>*</em>
<img title=”Select date” id=”_dob_trig” src=”<?php echo $this-  
>getSkinUrl(‘images/calendar.gif’);?>” class=”v-middle”>
</div>
</div>

<script type=”text/javascript”>
//<![CDATA[
Calendar.setup({
inputField : '_dob',
ifFormat : '%m/%e/%y',
button : '_dob_trig',
align : 'Bl',
singleClick : true
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: You are going wrong way.Try to enable template hints and goto specific page and put there your date picker code.

Comment: check whether double and single quotes are proper.like "" or ''.

Comment: Yes there were some quotation problems and corrected them and put the code at shipping_method.phtml page. But now checkout is not working.

Comment: @koli the problem description is not sufficient. Plese describe on which checkout step is not  working and what error you're getting.

Comment: @ vickram, i want to add a custom module to Magento that has a desired delivery date for customers to select when they buy goods and this was my first step. At this moment checkout page is displayed and Billing Information,Shipping Information and Shipping Method links are displayed. But not working.

Comment: @Keyur Shah Can you please mention how to download it, as i tried to download it and could not.

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/how_to_use_magentoconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather than developing extension you can use this free extension it will solve your problem

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-delivery-date-7864.html

if you don't know about how to download and how to its working please check this

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/how_to_use_magentoconnect

if you don't able to download extension from magento back-end then you can download manually from

http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

just put key here and and download and copy folder as per require

Comment: Ok thanks Keyur Shah and i installed it and want to know is there another things to do in order get it worked. When i clicked on Delivery Date link,  it shows error 404.

Comment: is this extension compatible with the Magento 1.7.2.0 ?

Comment: yes it works fine i am also using this,,please logout and login and clear cache and turn off compilation if enable it works fine,,

Comment: Thanks a lot keyur. It works. Can i customize this extension a bit as my need?

Comment: welcome ,,,ya you can customize as per your requirement

Comment: can you please tell me that the order date is going to shipments table or not? if not how do i fix it? please suggest me an answer.

Comment: no its going to quote table and order table and deliverydate table

Comment: what is your goal to store data in shipment?

Comment: I want to inform admin about the shipment date and in the system i'm developing, the person who does shipment must be able to see the due delivery dates. Does this extension send the captured delivery date to shipments table(in admin menu)?

Comment: this date is also show in order detail page,please checkout,means admin can see date

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44604/discussion-between-koli-and-keyur-shah)

Comment: @KeyurShah, the urls are not exist now